# Exclude local sub-net (local IP ranges)

Tags: vpn, ip, subnet, localhost

In my company's VPN app we have a disable-able feature which excludes below **List** of non-web-site IP-address ranges from being routed into the VPN server.

This allows local-net Apps to continue working even if the VPN is active, and in addition, some **Anti-VPN**s check these addresses (to see if VPN is active or not).

My qustion is, is there any IP-range we should add and/or remove from the list?

In addition, mentioning related RFC would be helpful, but not required.

**WARNING:** adding too much to List means leaking Web-site packets, and removing too much means local-net Apps may not work.

### List:

Legend:

- For example, the `{172,16,0,0 , 12},` entry means `172.16.0.0/12`.
- Where, first 4 fields of `MyType` specify the IP address's base.
- The 5th field specifies the "mask".

Entries:

```cpp
MyType localSubnets[] = {
    // Address ranges below are reserved by IANA for private intranets,
    // and not routable to the Internet
    // (For additional information, see RFC 1918).
    {10,0,0,0 , 8}, {10,170,60,224 , 27},
    {172,16,0,0 , 12},
    {192,168,0,0 , 16},
    // Reserved and special use addresses:
    {0,0,0,0 , 8}, // Current network (only valid as source address) RFC 1700
    {127,0,0,0 , 8}, // Loopback IP addresses (refers to self) RFC 5735
    {192,0,0,0 , 24}, // Reserved (IANA) RFC 5735
    {192,88,99,0 , 24}, // IPv6 to IPv4 relay. RFC 3068

    {198,18,0,0 , 15}, // Network benchmark tests. RFC 2544
    {198,51,100,0 , 24}, // TEST-NET-2. RFC 5737
    {203,0,113,0 , 24}, // TEST-NET-3. RFC 5737
    {224,0,0,0 , 4}, // Reserved for multicast addresses. RFC 3171
    // Reserved (former Class E network) RFC 1700
    {255,255,255,255 , 32} // Broadcast address (limited to all other nodes on the LAN) RFC 919
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to add:

- **169.254.0.0/16** - RFC 3927 - The block designed for local-link addresses. These addresses are automatically assigned to devices on local network when DHCP server is unavailable. They have limited scope and are not routable beyond the local network segment
- **240.0.0.0/4** -  This block is reserved for future purposes and should not be used for any current applications (IANA IP Address Space Registry)
- **64.44.0.0/16** - RFC 6459 - Used for Private Use for Carrier-grade NAT. This block allows service providers to create private address spaces for their customers behind a large NAT device.
- **100.64.0.0/10** - RFC 6598 - Designated for Shared Address Space for Carrier-grade NAT. This allows multiple service providers to share a pool of addresses for their customers behind NAT devices.
- **233.252.0.0/14** - RFC 791 - Multicast for Local Scope. It allows for efficient communication within a local network segment without needing individual routing for each device
- **239.255.0.0/16** - RFC 3171 - this block is designated for limited-scope multicast addresses. These addresses are used for specific purposes like service discovery within a local network.

Comment: I will accept this later, because some people don't bother answering if there is something already accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think OP should add `169.254.203.0/24` to said list, like:

```
{169,254,203,0 , 24}, // Link-local address.
```

> **Note** that I am the OP'er, but was yet not sure enough to add it to the list.

Comment: As the other answer(s) mentioned, the correct notation is `169.254.0.0/16` - however, may not delete this for historical reasons.